# Suggestions on a font I can use for both Android and iOS that looks similar to the system default fonts of each

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Android and iOs Forms application that currently uses the default fonts of each OS.  I would like both applications to look as similar as possible.

Are there any font packages that I could use for this and how could I implement this functionality. I realize that selection of fonts is something that many people could have different opinions but some started suggestions and any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think, you can use some common `FontFamily` for this.
[As from this tutorial](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/using-custom-fonts-on-ios-and-android-with-xamarin-forms/), you have to add a font you want (.ttf format)
and for each platform you need to do the following things:
iOS:

> Open your info.plist in your favorite text editor and at this section.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>Fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf</string>
<string>Fonts/Stackyard.ttf</string>
<string>Fonts/ComicSaaaaaans.ttf</string>
</array>
```

> From there you can use the iOS Appearance API to apply your font to whatever you want. In my case this was the navigation bar, which resulted in this:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes
{
   TextColor = UIColor.White,
   Font = UIFont.FromName("Stackyard PERSONAL USE", 32)
});
```

For Android:

> Now what we need to do is create a CustomRenderer for the controls in
>   which we want to show our fonts!
>   A obvious choice is the Label control. When we define a renderer with
>   this code overriding the ElementChanged we can use the StyleId, like
>   you’ve seen above, to specify which font to use right from our shared
>   code!

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
{
   base.OnElementChanged(e);

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewElement?.StyleId))
   {
      var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, e.NewElement.StyleId + ".ttf");

       Control.Typeface = font;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)