# Font awesome icon not showing up in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

Font awesome icons are not working for me in Xamarin.Forms. This is my `Label` xaml

```
<Label TextColor="Red" FontFamily="FontAwesomeBrands"  FontSize="Large" Text="&#xf122;"
RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Width,Factor=1}">
</Label>
```

I have added these file in `Assests` folder of android project

[image]

*Output just showing empty symbol*. how can I make it work?

Comment: I could be crazy but is there a typo?  The font name is FontAwesome5Brands but you have it without the 5 in the XAML.

Comment: Not working. I tried setting `FontAwesome5Brands` and `FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular`.

Comment: You read and followed this ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts

Comment: What version of XF are you using? The `FontIconSource` should be available in 3.6 to make your life easier: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3189

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - That seems something else. Not understanding at all. :)

Comment: Have you tried to use other type of font?Such as  xxx.ttf.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - Where can I find xxx.ttf file?

Comment: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/popular

Answer (score 1):

Have you created platform-specific `CustomRenderers` for that?

Please, look at my answer, and follow the tutorial. [Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55453294/4251242)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. But this is not really I am looking for. Seems FA icons can be used without custom renderer too.

Answer (score 1):

I use Xam.FormsPlugin.Iconize and Xam.Plugin.Iconize NuGet packages for icons:

```
xmlns:iconize="clr-namespace:FormsPlugin.Iconize;assembly=FormsPlugin.Iconize" 

<iconize:IconLabel Text="fa-question-circle" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#666666" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
```

Comment: This is asking to downgrade xamarin forms library 3.5 t 3.2.